# Azure CLI - get Resource Group Id

Tags: azure-cli

I'm trying to obtain the Resource Group Id using Azure CLI using the RG name.

I have tried the following but to no avail:

```
$scopeId = (az group list --query $exemption.ResourceGroupName).Id
```

and:

```
$scopeId = (az group list --query "[?name==$exemption.ResourceGroupName]").Id
```

The underlying Json in the exemption object is as follows (values removed or replaced):

```
[    
      {
        "scope": "Resource Group",
        "scopeName": "",
        "scopeNameFull": "/providers/Microsoft.Management/managementgroups/",
        "exemptionCategory": "Waiver",
        "name": "",
        "description": "My Exemption description",
        "expiresOn": null,
        "ResourceName": null,
        "ResourceGroupName": "rg",
        "subscriptionId": "123",
        "policyDefinitionReferenceIds": [ "policy1", "policy2"]
      }      
]
```

Comment: Which shell are u using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, I could able to get this done using the below script.

```
$a=az group list --query "[?name=='<YOUR_RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>']" |ConvertFrom-Json
$a.id
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use the `show` subcommand:

```
$scopeId = (az group show -n $exemption.ResourceGroupName -o tsv --query id)
```